# Startup application not receiving focus

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, google-chrome

We have some tablets that have a web app running in Google Chrome on Windows 10. I put a shortcut in the startup folder to automatically start Chrome and it starts with Windows. However, the window stays minimized until you click on it. Is there a  way to make  Chrome maximized on startup, maybe as a registry entry?

I tried setting the `ForegroundLockTimeout` to 0 in registry editor under `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you clarify "disable"?  Are you saying you want Chrome to start maximized?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I want Chrome to be maximized on startup

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)
with the following script :

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", , max
Sleep, 3000
winmaximize Google Chrome
```

The winmaximize call after the wait for Chrome to start is for ensuring that
Chrome is displayed as maximized.